# How to pass a value from an ArrayList to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have an `RecyclerView` which sould simulate a newsfeed. I want, that if you click on an item of the `RecyclerView`, that the text of this item is shown in another `Fragment's` `TextView`. The text of the posts inside the newsfeed are saved in a `ArrayList`. I've tried for many hours to pass an Value of the `ArrayList` to the `TextView` in the `Fragment` where it's supposed to be shown, but i really don't get it. Here's my code:

**RecyclerView adapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RvAdapterKlasseTalkFragment extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapterKlasseTalkFragment.ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment>{


    public static class ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView userName;
        TextView postText;
        // IMAGE FÜR DEN POST FEHLT!!!!!!!!!
        TextView zeit;
        TextView anzahlKommentare;
        TextView anzahlLikes;
        ImageButton moreButton;

        TextView loeschen;

        public  ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            postText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postText);
            zeit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zeit);
            anzahlKommentare = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.anzahlKommentare);
            anzahlLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.anzahlLikes);
            moreButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
            loeschen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.loeschen);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.iten_layout_post, null);
        return new ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment(itemView1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment viewHolderKlasse,final int i) {
        viewHolderKlasse.userName.setText(TalkscreenFragment.userName);
        viewHolderKlasse.userName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ProfilePopUp.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        viewHolderKlasse.postText.setText(TalkscreenFragment.postText.get(i));
        viewHolderKlasse.zeit.setText(TalkscreenFragment.currentDateTimeString);
        viewHolderKlasse.anzahlKommentare.setText(TalkscreenFragment.anzahlKommentare);
        viewHolderKlasse.anzahlLikes.setText(TalkscreenFragment.anzahlLikes);
        viewHolderKlasse.moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ContextMenuPopUp.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TalkscreenFragment.postText.size();
    }
}
```

**Activity with ArrayList and RecylcerView**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class Talkscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static LinearLayoutManager rvLayoutManagerTalkFragment;
    public static RecyclerView recyclerViewTalkFragment;
    public static RecyclerView.Adapter rvadapterTalkFragment;

    public static ArrayList<String> postText;

    public static String userName = "Benutzer 1";
    public static String anzahlKommentare = "1.243";
    public static String anzahlLikes = "15540";
    public static String currentDateTimeString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_talkscreen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        TextView meineaktivitaeten = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meineAktivitaeten);
        meineaktivitaeten.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MeineAktivitaeten.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        postText = new ArrayList<>();
        postText.addAll(Arrays.asList("TEXT 1",
                "TEXT 2",
                "TEXT 3",
                "TEXT 4"));

        currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        recyclerViewTalkFragment = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleviewTalkFragment);
        rvLayoutManagerTalkFragment = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewTalkFragment.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManagerTalkFragment);
        rvadapterTalkFragment = new RvAdapterKlasseTalkFragment();
        recyclerViewTalkFragment.setAdapter(rvadapterTalkFragment);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_talkscreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.einstellungen) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Einstellungen.class));
        }


        if (id == R.id.information) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Fragment where the ArrayList value is supposed to be shown**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MeinePosts extends Fragment {


    public static MeinePosts newInstance(){
        MeinePosts fragment = new MeinePosts();
        return fragment;
    }

    public MeinePosts() {
    }

    TextView postedText;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meine_posts, container, false);

        postedText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postTextMeinePosts);


        return rootView;

    }


}
```

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

in

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MeinePosts extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<String> fragmentList;

    public static MeinePosts newInstance(){
        MeinePosts fragment = new MeinePosts();
        return fragment;
    }

    /*HERE YOU RECIVE PARAMETER ARRAYLIST*/
    public MeinePosts(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        /*Now from here you can set the arraylist
          to other...  it can be access from any method
          if you set on class*/
          fragmentList = myList;
    }

    TextView postedText;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meine_posts, container, false);

        postedText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postTextMeinePosts);


        return rootView;

    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm relatively new to android programming, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for interfragment communication in Android is through interfaces in both Fragments, with the Activity as the man-in-the-middle.
In order to do this, you have to declare an Interface for the fragment that you want to make able to send information to the activity.

First do this in your Fragment RvAdapterKlasseTalkFragment:
    public class RvAdapterKlasseTalkFragment extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    // Declare this interface
    public Interface AdapterInterface() {
        public void sendValueToActivity(String value);
    }

    // Create an object to reference the activity that implements the previous interface (Talkscreen)
    AdapterInterface activityConnection;

    // in your onclick call the interface
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderKlasseTalkFragment viewHolderKlasse,final int i) {
        viewHolderKlasse.userName.setText(TalkscreenFragment.userName);
        viewHolderKlasse.userName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                connectedActivity.sendValueToActivity(myvalue);
            }
        });

    // here is where you link the interface to the activity and you can openly exchange information now
     @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            activityConnection = (AdapterInterface) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement AdapterInterface");
        }
    }

}
```

In your MeineFragment set a method that you can call from the Activity directly referencing the fragment object of this class:

```
public class MeinePosts extends Fragment {

    // add this method to your MeinePosts fragment
    public void setTextViewValue(String value) {
        postedText.setText(value);
    }

}
```

And finally in your Activity implement the interface declared in the first fragment:

```
public class Talkscreen extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void sendValueToActivity(String value) {
        // here invoque a method in the second fragment for example
        AdapterFragment.setTextViewValue(value);
    }
}
```

In case you also need to send information from the second fragment to the first one, you also need to implement the same steps (declaring interface in second fragment, implement it in the activity, linking it in the fragment, and in the activity call a new method in the first fragment to do what you want)

I have this project in Github doing inter-fragment communication if you still need more info.
https://github.com/isaacurbina/FragmentsExercise

I hope it helps! Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there was a terrible mistake that I've made. The initialised TextView in the **MeinePost Fragment** was referring to a RelativeLayout and not an TextView.

Ongoing I found a relatively simple way to achieve what I wanted. It is probably not the best solution, but it works for me:

1st step:

**RecyclerView adapter**

```
viewHolderKlasse.postText.setText(Talkscreen.postText.get(i));
        viewHolderKlasse.postText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AngeklickterPost.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", Talkscreen.postText.get(i)); //data is a string variable holding some value.
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

2nd step: I needed to create a new Activity for my intentions

**AngeklickterPost Activity**

```
package com.appmac.ron.gamestalk;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AngeklickterPost extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_angeklickter_post);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
        TextView postTextPosted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postTextPosted);
        postTextPosted.setText(data);
    }

}
```

Hope this post is helpful for people that might have the same problem. If there is something I could do better, please comment!